# Odd Behavior from Date.strptime()

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a date conversion using strptime and it is normalizing my data to always have 2020 as the year and I'm not sure why. Specifically:

```
value = "2015/03/21"
value2 = Date.strptime(value, '%m/%d/%y')
```

produces a result where value2 = "2020-03-21" How do I get Date.strptime() to appropriately reflect the year?

Comment: It seems that your code is incomplete.  Unless I'm mistaken, you should be getting an error with the code as posted.  The last line SHOULD be ```value2 = Date.strptime(value, '%Y/%m/%d')```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `strptime` is the input format in which the date is provided not the expected output format. Therefore change it to:

```
value = "2015/03/21"
value2 = Date.strptime(value, '%Y/%m/%d')
#=> #<Date: 2015-03-21 ((2457103j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I'd also note that the %Y is capitalized. For some reason having a lowercase %y was altering the year to 2020, which I'm not sure why that behavior was occurring.

Comment: `%Y` expects the year as four digits including the century (2022), whereas `%y` expects two digits (22 without the century). Have a look at http://strftime.net/  or [`Date#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) to read about the different directives available.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0):

In `value` year is first, month is second. You want to create date object from string, so to correctly parse you should use correct order:

```rb
value = "2015/03/21"
value2 = Date.strptime(value, '%Y/%m/%d')
 => Sat, 21 Mar 2015
```